# javascript animate height while get new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a string like

```
content = "content1<br/>content2<br/>"
```

and I add `content3` into string the result gonna be like

```
content1
content2
content3
```

I want the container of `content` animate height while showing new content.

I have tried

```
document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = content;
$("detail").animate({
     height: 'auto'
}, 1000);
```

it's just appear without animate

Comment: You can't animate height to 'auto', it needs to be in fixed px or %

Comment: First of all, the code you are giving us is something between javascript and jQuery. Decide what you are using and use this only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tricky to animate to unknown height. I would try to make use of the combination of CSS transition and javascript helper function to calculate new width.

Of course you can still go with just `animate` but you will still need to calculate new height and animate to new height.

```js
var content = "content1<br/>content2<br/>";

var height = getHeight(content);
$("#detail").css('max-height', height).html(content);

setTimeout(function() {
    content += 'content3<br/>';
    var height = getHeight(content);
    $("#detail").css('max-height', height).html(content);
}, 1000);

function getHeight(str) {
    var $tmp = $("<div>").html(content).css({position: 'absolute', top: -1000}).appendTo('body'),
        height = $tmp.height() + 10 + 'px';
    $tmp.remove();
    return height;
}
```

```css
#detail {
    background: #EEE;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="detail"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because jQuery .Animate() only works with numbers.

for example your current height is: `20px` and you make it `30px` in animate function.

jQuery will rise 20 to 30 in the declared time and set it to the element continuously until it gets to 30.

on the other hand CSS acts more quickly than JS and makes the element auto-heighted automatically.

So you have to use numbers to animate the new height (and the previous height has to be a number too) OR you can use CSS3 transitions.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdghasemi/1u7zqs4j/) here